# Java ME SDK emulator options

Tags: java-me

For one of the older versions of Java ME SDK emulators I found this tutorial http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/wtk2.5.2/docs/UserGuide-html/projects.html

I am looking for similar options for the version 3.0, but the device manager won't open or show me any option windows.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the options to set the Emulator speeds etc.

thanks

~ Kyle

Answer (score 0):

I can find those settings using Netbeans 6.8. AFAIK the Java ME SDK is just a "reduced" version of Netbeans with some graphic midlet editor. I would use just Netbeans.